# What is in side of empty default parentheses? Why are they there?

Tags: vb.net

Sub Main()

Console.Read()

I asked this before,,, what is inside empty default parentheses, does any one know?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice ?

Answer (score 2):

The first says:

> This is a subroutine called Main and **it takes** no Parameters.

The second says;

> Please call the Read subroutine/function and **don't pass** it any parameters

so `()` implies no parameters and is simply a syntactic construct to allow the programmer to pass the intention above to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is inside.   the parentheses are there to show the member is a method.  A property would not have the parentheses.

Comment: In VB.NET the parenthesis for procedure/method calls are optional when no argument list is supplied. (Can a Property and a Method even/ever have the same name?)

Comment: @user2864740 Optional but still provide some clarity.  I'm not sure if a property and method can have the same name in vb.net, properties are really just an easier way to write a set and get method anyway.  Still if you see parens you know its a method so it does help readability slightly if done consistently.